# How to create a nw.js build with out dev tools

Tags: nw.js, npm-scripts

I have successfully build and tested a `nw.js` app with version *0.21.6* sdk. However I now want to create a version I can publish i.e. without the dev tools however whatever I do it always gets build with the sdk

Todo this

1. I deleted the `node_modules` folder for the app
2. I executed `npm install nw@0.21.6` from the command line (i.e. without the sdk suffix)
3. I executed `npm install nw-builder --save-dev`
4. I executed my `npm prod` script which is the string `"nwbuild --platforms osx64 --buildDir dist/ --macIns src/ap.icns src/"`

However the builder downloaded and used *0.21.6* sdk

I have tried adding `--flavour normal` to the `prod` script - no difference
I have cleared my npm cache - no difference

Please can someone tell me how to achieve this.

P.S. when I run from my `dev` script  `"nw src/"`  there is no command line access, so that bit of it seems fine. What drives the builder to download and use the sdk version?

Comment: I saw elsewhere that this issue has been experienced by others but had been reported as fixed in version 3.2.0 two weeks ago. Has it returned?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by switching to the use of nw-builder-phoenix (in place of nw-builder)